# Cannot Read Modified Value from JSON file Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to read the value from the JSON file . I have created a configuration folder under which i have created a config.json file.

Under the JSOn file i have defined my baseUrl

```
{
"baseUrl": "http://localhost:8085"
}
```

In my service i am using the below code to load the JSON:

```
export function createConfiguration(): Configuration {
    console.log('############### createConfiguration started ####################');
    debugger;
    let config: Configuration;
    let config1: Configuration;
    let profile = process.env.CONFIG_PROFLE;
    console.log('Profile ' + profile);
    if (profile) {
        // config = Object.assign(
        //     new Configuration(profile),
        //     require('./../../../configuration/config.json'),
        //     require('./../../../configuration/config-' + process.env.CONFIG_PROFILE + '.json')
        // );
    } else {
        config = Object.assign(
            new Configuration(profile),
            require('./../../assets/config/config.json'));
        console.log('configuration file loaded: ', config);



        config1 = Object.assign(
            new Configuration(profile),
            require('./../../../configuration/config.json')
            // require('./../../../configuration/config-' + process.env.CONFIG_PROFILE + '.json')
        );
        console.log('configuration1 file loaded: ', config1);

    }

    console.log('############### createConfiguration ended ####################');

    return config;
};
```

Every things works well when i am doing

> ng serve

build as soon as i am using

> ng build --prod

and deploying the js file in server i am facing some issue .

1.When i manually trying to change the baseUrl to some other url then its not reflected in the URL because i guess angular is building the existing defined JSON and putting in the main.bundle.js .

Can anyone help me how i can achieve this.

Comment: You should put the baseUrl in envirement

Comment: @LucianBumb you mean system environment .

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3539

Comment: @LucianBumb sorry to say but i don't want to try this although i was aware of this approach the reason is i don't want to put something which will be a part of my build lets say if my ip changes i need to change in my fie and then provide the build . Instead i want to put this in some configuration file where i can change this on fly and just restart the server without building the code. I hope u will understand my concern here.